# Razor passing values between domains

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm new to .NET, and try to work with Razor.
I have 100 domains, all about places. 
My question is: Is it possible to have a page, per domain, which passes Place ID to a Razor Folder containing Default.cshtml, somewhere on the Server. Default.cshtml page regulates all  the requests for all domains including DB connection, _Layout, etc etc...? 
To put it simple: the domain paris.com has only two tags: PlaceID And includeFile/General Domain/Default.aspx
Default.aspx sees PlaceID and acts accordingly. But Include doesn't exist by Razor...

Comment: I added some more tags for a broader audience. Having just 1 tag is not going to get your question answered.

Comment: No worries, we all have to go thru this phase :)

Comment: Hi Brendan, sure. But do you know the answer to my question? Till now I worked with ColdFusion, it goes quite smooth, one Index.cfm regulates 1000 sites, just by passing one simple ID.

Comment: @Brendan I undid your edits as tag spam isn't really appreciated. The correct way to a good answer is asking a good question, not applying as many tags as possible to it. Currently this question is too vague. OP - Can you elaborate a bit more on what exactly you want to do and what you tried to accomplish that? At least I can say you don't want to initiate database connections from a view.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Why would you consider it tag spamming? The OP only had the razor tag there. So I added the ASP.NET and MVC tags. There are currently about 750 followers for just razor. So what you saying is that a broader audience will not get more eyes on his question??

Comment: @Brendan of course more tags will draw more views, I'm just saying one `asp.net-mvc` tag is enough, so I removed `asp.net`, `asp.net-mvc-3` and `asp.net-mvc-4`. :-) See [Vast majority of questions tagged asp.net and mvc should be tagged asp.net-mvc](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126852/vast-majority-of-questions-tagged-asp-net-and-mvc-should-be-tagged-asp-net) and [Tagging best practices](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80039/tagging-best-practices).

Comment: Hey user2591090, I think we could all still do with a little more concerning the problem.  Maybe you could post some the the original cold fusion code you're trying to port.

Comment: That said it sounds like you've hit on one of the fundamental differences between cold fusion and asp.net MVC, where in cold fusion a url goes straight to a document which contains a script which then runs and produces output asp.net mvc gives you greater flexibility by having the URL map to a controller action, this is a piece of code that does the heavy lifting, connecting to databases etc and then passes a model to a razor view which then renders the output.

Comment: HI Chris, I'm very glad to hear that Razo can do it even better.

Comment: Here Code: (just a part of it):

Comment: This is index.cfm by paris.com <cfset PlaceID = 161><br>
<cfinclude template="../place.cfm">  What then the place.cfm is doeing: (simplified query): SELECT Place FROM PlaceID WHERE PlaceID = #PlaceID# so, there is no passing variable thru URL or Form...